# Is there an adjective to say "will be maintained up-to-date"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I would like to say the following:

> an up-to-date database which will be maintained up-to-date

This sentence is nested within a larger sentence, therefore I would like to keep it as short as possible, without losing the two ideas: the database is currently up-to-date, and the database will be maintained up-to-date in the future. My co-authors suggested:

> a current yet updatable database

But I do not think this is correct in English (more-or-less direct translation from French). I am struggling to find a decent, short way to formulate this sentence. I would appreciate any help. Perhaps there is an English expression to say that?

Comment: A configurable database, pre-populated by Foo and updated weekly by Baz, will be used ?

Comment: "...maintained up-to-date" sounds odd to me, I would say "will be kept up to date". You are correct that "updatable database" is incorrect in this context, because it just means it is possible to update the database, not that it necessarily will be updated.

Comment: What about 'latest', like, latest database? It naturally means current and updated.

Comment: Sometimes complex ideas need to be explained at some length.  Sometimes brevity  does not lead to a clear enough explanation.  Personally I see nothing wrong (grammatically or semantically) with your original statement though, like your colleagues I could kick it stylistically.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I agree, maybe brevity is not possible here. I will choose something close to this for now: "a database that will be kept up-to-date". The context of this database is not an informatics / online database; it is a science database that we keep up-to-date with the scientific literature we monitor. Hence, suggestions by @ķ̢̫̬̺͚̻͚̹̙̔̎ͣ͆͛͛ and Ram Pillai (thanks) are difficult to apply here.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say the database will be "regularly updated" or "updated regularly".

Comment: Answers should provide citations. Please edit the answer to include a link to this usage in action.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It conveys an idea similar to what we wanted, and we will consider it.